# Select equations with RHS!=0 from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I need to select from a list containing equations those having RHS not zero

```
list = {a == 0, b == 1, c == 0, d == e}
Select[list, #[[2]] != 0 &]
Select[list, #[[2]] == 0 &]
```

I cannot process properly the list to include `d==e`.

Where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Because `!=` and `==` do not guarantee to return either `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1):

`Equal` (`==`) and `Unequal` (`!=`) often do not evaluate if one of its sides is symbolic (or contains symbols). That's a feature that you actually use in your list `list` of equations; otherwise, it would read as follows:

```
{False, False, False, False}
```

So, better use `SameQ` (`===`) and `UnsameQ` (`=!=`)

```
Select[list, #[[2]] =!= 0 &]
Select[list, #[[2]] === 0 &]
```

> {b == 1, d == e}
>
> {a == 0, c == 0}

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, Equal[_, Except[0]]]
```

> {b == 1, d == e}

```
Cases[list, Equal[_, 0]]
```

> {a == 0, c == 0}